# docker-entrypoint.sh: line 113: conf/neo4j.conf: Permission denied

Tags: docker, neo4j, openshift

Deploying docker Neo4J image using openshift and I'm getting this error:

```
docker-entrypoint.sh: line 113: conf/neo4j.conf: Permission denied.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue on open shift?

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile` and your `docker-entrypoint.sh`

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift will by default run your image as an assigned user ID, not what your `Dockerfile` says to run as. You need to ensure you filesystem permissions are set so as to allow a user running with group `root` is able to access them, and modify as well if necessary. It will be group `root` as the user ID it runs as will not be in the `passwd` file on the container so it will fallback to using group ID of `0`, corresponding to `root` group.

Comment: To follow that up: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

If images aren't created with those guidelines then there will be difficulty getting them to run.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j images in https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j are assuming that you have `root` access, but in OpenShift you don't get root access by default.

Try to add your `RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/neo4j` to your `Dockerfile` like this https://github.com/mahabdelaziz/docker-neo4j/blob/master/src/3.4/Dockerfile